# How to show Alert Dialog in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to display a `AlertDialog` with a list of items. The list should be two dimensional. On pressing the a button the dialog should be displayed. So how should i do it? Is there a need to create a xml file seperately for the alert dialog or should I include the dialog in java code itself?

Comment: If you know how to define custom adapter then it is easy for you to define custom dialog as you have mentioned.

Comment: u hav to to create dialog....which will include ur created xmlfile

Comment: using `setView()` method, you can set any view to your alert dialog.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10652886/1168654

Answer (score 3):

To create Alert Dialog,

```
public void Alert(String text, String title)
    { 
        AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        dialog.setTitle(title);
        dialog.setMessage(text);
        if(!title.equals("") && !text.equals(""))
        {
            dialog.setButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                           //
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setButton2("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                           //
                        }
                    });
        }

        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the code but which package should i include for DialogInterface...because it is showing some error on Dialog Interface

Comment: import android.content.DialogInterface;

Comment: thanks and its working...What i have to do to include 2 items in each row in a list?

Comment: refer this http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2010/12/custom-gridview-in-dialog.html

Comment: this makes use of a gridview..is there any other method out so that it  shows two elements without the help of gridview

Comment: you meant you want to show multible lines ah? if yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913166/displaying-multiple-lines-of-text-and-variables-in-an-alertdialog-using-setmessa

Comment: suppose i have three elements red, blue and green.Now i want to add a image with all of three elements..how is it posible ..every row with show the name and colour of element

Comment: Check this: http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/10/arrayadapter-and-alertdialog-for-single-choice-items/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a dialog themed activity and pop it up instead of the Dialog?

If you insist on creating a Dialog. Here is a piece of code that you can try out.

```
//Class Level Variables:
CharSequence[] items = { "Google", "Apple", "Microsoft" };
boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];

//Call this when you want a dialog
showdialog(0);

//override onCreateDialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) { 
    switch (id) {
    case 0:         
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
            int whichButton) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                     "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                int whichButton) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                     "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })            
        .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new 
            DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {                  
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!": " unchecked!"), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        )
        .create();
}
```

This creates an AlertDialog which has a checkbox and name.....